# Why does my ListView stack views on top of each other instead of vertically cascading downwards?

Tags: android

I am returning a Custom View that extends RelativeLayout.

How can I fix this? Thanks.

This is the listview:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/view_container"
        android:layout_below="@+id/optionBarContainer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="-8px" 
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        >
    </ListView>
```

This is the adapter:

```
public class OptionBarListViewArrayAdapter extends
        ArrayAdapter<UserCheckpointBean> {

    public OptionBarListViewArrayAdapter(Context context,
            UserCheckpointBean[] beans) {
        super(context, R.layout.checkpoint_tab, beans);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        UserCheckpointBean userCheckpointBean = getItem(position);
        CheckpointTabView view = new CheckpointTabView(getContext());

        view.setData(userCheckpointBean);

        return view;
    }

}
```

Comment: picture please. or code.

Comment: This can't be answered in its current form. Please include source code and a screen shot showing the issue.

Comment: Because it's because how RelativeLayouts work? As long as you don't put the other view `above/below` the first.

Comment: But the relativelayouts are not nested within each other. They are neighbours. They shouldn't stack.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out why, I made a n00b mistake by nesting the Listview within a Scrollview.